# In React how to determine when DOM is ready?

Tags: reactjs

The method ReactDOM.render has a callback which

> will be executed after the component is rendered or updated

Does this mean when the DOM is ready? (E.g. as in jQuery.ready() )

This becomes an issue when running a selenium test. For example:

1. navigate to url which (using router) will cause a set of components to render

   browser.get(url)
2. test for some text on the page

   assertTrue 'testword' in browser.page_text

The callback is on the outermost (top-level) component. It does seem to wait until all its children are rendered. But - will it be called only when the DOM is rendered - or just when React has finished posting its updates to the DOM? If the former the test may incorrectly fail.

Comment: It's called when react has finished rendering, normally the script which includes react and your app goes at the bottom of the body, when the DOM is already ready

Comment: Have you tried initializing tests from ComponentDidMount()? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount